# Why do most Scala libraries use mutable RNG

Tags: scala, random, functional-programming, immutability

In the Cats documentation an appealing implementation of a [pure functional PRNG](https://typelevel.org/cats/datatypes/state.html#purely-functional-pseudorandom-values) is given when describing the use of the State monad. However, the libraries I have seen (Breeze, Spire) make use of mutable generators. Why? Also, are there any libraries that make use of the Cats approach?

Comment: I don't think this question is a good fit at [so]. 1) Tt contains two questions, so the *actual* question being asked is unclear. 2) The second question being asked is a resource request and thus off-topic. 3) The first question being asked can only be answered by the authors of Breeze and Spire. If they have published that information somewhere, then the question is a resource request and thus off-topic. If they haven't, then the question is asking to read their minds and thus un-answerable.

Comment: If I had to make a guess, though, I would have one idea: yes, dealing with mutable state is *hard*. But, writing a good PRNG, especially a CSPRNG is also hard. Maybe, the authors just thought that dealing with the mutable state of an already existing, vetted, battle-tested PRNG would be easier than creating their own? Note that especially for a CSPRNG, not only the cryptographic properties are important but also the performance. Otherwise, your super-safe super-pure CSPRNG just becomes an attack vector for a DoS attack. Also, beware of timing attacks and other side channels.

Comment: In particular, the RNG you linked to has some well-known disadvantages, and is not recommended for cryptographic usage.

Comment: Feel free to put the second comment as your answer and I’ll accept. Thank you.

Comment: Cats example is just a demo showing how State monad can be used to replace global state. But as it was mentioned it isn't suitable for crypto or any other work where you _need_ nondeterminism. In pure FP that would need it I'd rather expect SecureRandom wrapped in IO monad: Cats IO, Monix Task or ZIO. But there is a lot of use cases where you need neither so plain old Random is good enough.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Jörg W Mittag wrote the following in comments:

> If I had to make a guess, though, I would have one idea: yes, dealing with mutable state is hard. But, writing a good PRNG, especially a CSPRNG is also hard. Maybe, the authors just thought that dealing with the mutable state of an already existing, vetted, battle-tested PRNG would be easier than creating their own? Note that especially for a CSPRNG, not only the cryptographic properties are important but also the performance. Otherwise, your super-safe super-pure CSPRNG just becomes an attack vector for a DoS attack. Also, beware of timing attacks and other side channels.
>
> In particular, the RNG you linked to has some well-known disadvantages, and is not recommended for cryptographic usage.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the accepted answer misses the point. Breeze & Spire don't use a mutable RNG due to the quality of the RNG itself. They do it for *programmatic convenience*.

Functional RNGs require writing the program in state-monad form (as shown in the Cats documentation), typically with all usages of the RNG in for-expressions. If other monadic effects like `Option`, `Future` etc are present, they'd need to be composed via eg monad-transformers.